# How to access req.user in mongoose Model Schema hooks?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am using `express 4`, `mongoose 4.5` and `passport 0.3` and i want to automating assign value from `req.user` object in my model at particular field. for example

**model schema**

```
var leadSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastUpdateId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    }
});
```

**req.user data**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57ce86af9d5639ef104149fb"),
    "name" : "Vineet Sah"
}
```

Now i need here that `req.user._id` is automatic assign at `lastUpdateId` when i create new from `leadSchema`.

Something like:-

```
leadSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    var self = this;
    //self.lastUpdateId = req.user._id   
})
```